# Running django standalone scripts in the crontab destroys any import commands related to django

Tags: python, django, cron

I have tried many many solutions to fixing this, including using django's custom management commands, python scripts with path configuration and setting the DJANGO_ENV_VAR, etc. Everything breaks when I try to import something from django specifically, like:

```
from django.db
```

or

```
import django.utils
```

Here is an example of one of my error tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/username/webapps/folder/Project/scripts/standalone.py", line 29, in 
<module> from Model.models import Model File "/home/username/webapps/folder/
Project/App/models.py", line 15, in <module> from django.db import models
ImportError: No module named django.db
```

In the crontab I followed all the general procedures. All of the time configs are correct, all the scripts are being called with their full paths, ie. /usr/bin/python2.7 or /usr/bin/sh.

When any of these scripts are run in the shell and not in crontab, it works just fine:
like:

```
python2.7 manage.py killModels
```

or

```
sh scrapper.sh >> log.log
```

Here is the crontab:

```
8,38,58 * * * * ~/webapps/Folder/apache2/bin/start
#*/1 * * * * /bin/sh ~/webapps/Folder/Project/scripts/unpack.sh >> ~/webapps/Folder/Project/logs/unpack.log 2>&1
*/25 * * * * ~/bin/indexer Model_Model --rotate --config    
~/webapps/Folder/Project/misc/sphinx/sphinx.conf >> ~/webapps/Folder/Project/logs/searchd_log.txt
*/25 * * * * /bin/sh ~/webapps/Folder/Project/scripts/check_sphinx.sh >> ~/webapps/Folder/Project/logs/searchd_log.txt
0 2 * * * mysqldump --defaults-file=~/db_backups/Project_db.cnf -u Project_db Project_db >  ~/db_backups/Project_db-`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.sql 2>> ~/db_backups/cron.log
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/Folder/Project/manage.py UpdateModels >> ~/webapps/Folder/Project/logs/unpack.log 2>&1
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: are you using a `virtualevn`? What specific errors are kyou getting? Are you getting ImportError?

Comment: No, im not using any form of virtualenv, should I? Is it needed? My exact error is: Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "/home/username/webapps/folder/Project/scripts/standalone.py", line 29, in 
   <module> from Model.models import Model File "/home/username/webapps/folder/
   Project/App/models.py", line 15, in <module> from django.db import models
   ImportError: No module named django.db

Comment: Lucas, post crontab line command. Have you tried to execute command in proper folder:  `* *  ( cd /path/to/project ; /path/to/python manage.py command ) `

Comment: Ok, the full crontab is now in the question.

Comment: I have not tried to execute the command in proper order, does it make a difference aside from syntactical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python2.7 \
            ~/webapps/Folder/Project/manage.py UpdateModels \
            >> ~/webapps/Folder/Project/logs/unpack.log 2>&1
```

by:

```
*/1 * * * * (cd ~/webapps/Folder/Project/; \
             /usr/local/bin/python2.7 manage.py UpdateModels) \
             >> ~/webapps/Folder/Project/logs/unpack.log 2>&1
```

With this change  `manage.py` would be able to locate django applications.

Comment: Thanks, i'll implement asap, but do you have any idea on how I can fix the import errors on my independent shell scripts, thats the more important one. The cron job for it is here: */1 * * * * /bin/sh ~/webapps/Folder/Project/scripts/unpack.sh >> ~/webapps/Folder/Project/logs/unpack.log 2>&1

Comment: For clarification, the shell script's sole purpose is to call a python script that does the above task, but it checks to see if the script itself is already running first. The error occurs in the python script once again, when the script calls models.py and errors out at import django.db, thanks.